Nonstandard Analysis in ZFC?
My interest in nonstandard analysis and its applications to physics is growing; however, it seems to me that most authors do not develop nonstandard analysis within ZFC.
Specifically, I’ve read about the first hundred pages of Robinson’s book, where the author doesn’t even use first-order logic. Instead, he develops a kind of simplified type theory. That said, I feel that the book is starting to feel a bit dated. I’ve also looked at the first few pages of Vakil’s Real Analysis Through Modern Infinitesimals, where the author works within Internal Set Theory.
However, it’s not difficult to construct hyperreals in ZFC, so I wonder: why bother constructing new axiomatizations?
Are there any good and recent books that develop nonstandard analysis within ZFC? If not, why is that the case?
Also it would be awesome if someone knew some good references to study functional analysis and distribution theory with nonstandard analysis.
Thanks in advance!

I have only seen NSA developed with respect to ZFC. I have not read Robinson specifically, but the Robinsionian approach (nonstandard extensions of superstructures and all) is based in ZFC. Internal Set Theory includes ZFC in it's axioms, and it is a conservative extension of ZFC (meaning every theorem of ZFC that has a proof in IST has a proof in ZFC).

Part of the appeal of axiomatic theories is that it does away with cruft: there is no such thing as "the hyperreals", there are infinitely many non-isomorphic hyperreal fields that fit within the framework of NSA.

@NicholasTodoroff: It's worth noting that IST-style theories can be developed on other substrates, not just ZFC. E.g. a chapter of my PhD thesis develops an analogue of IST over Martin-Löf type theory. Such a thing is not a conservative extension of MLTT, ofc: for decidable internal predicates $P(-)$ one has $\forall x < \omega. P(x) \vee \neg P(x)$, and so by Transfer $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}.P(x)\vee\neg P(x)$ follows, but this generally does not hold in MLTT.

@Z.A.K. That sounds fascinating, I will definitely have to take a look. Thank you!

Incidentally, if you are also interested in nonstandard analysis in ZF (without the "C"), I can provide some details, as well.

Examples of good books that develop nonstandard analysis in ZFC are

Davis, Martin. Applied nonstandard analysis. Pure and Applied Mathematics. Wiley-Interscience [John Wiley & Sons], New York-London-Sydney, 1977

and

Goldblatt, Robert.  Lectures on the hyperreals.  An introduction to nonstandard analysis. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 188. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1998.

As far as Robinson's 1966 book is concerned, it can be easily expressed in ZFC as well.  Robinson used the compactness theorem (instead of using ultrapower constructions) which is certainly a result in ZFC.
As far as distribution theory is concerned: this is certainly a vast subject.  Some of this was done in Robinson's 1966 book.  As might be expected, one can give an elegant construction of the Dirac delta "function" using infinitesimals; for an elementary discussion see e.g.

Katz, Mikhail G.; Tall, David.
A Cauchy-Dirac delta function.
Found. Sci. 18 (2013), no. 1, 107–123.

For applications in physics, see

Albeverio, Sergio; Høegh-Krohn, Raphael; Fenstad, Jens Erik; Lindstrøm, Tom. Nonstandard methods in stochastic analysis and mathematical physics. Pure and Applied Mathematics, 122. Academic Press, Inc., Orlando, FL, 1986.

Notice that, IST being conservative over ZFC, there is no obstruction to working in IST instead.  In fact, axiomatic approaches to nonstandard analysis have the advantage that they enable an analysis of the role of the various versions of the axioms of choice in analysis with infinitesimals (something that wasn't possible with the model-theoretic approaches).
